# Sugar CRM, Creating the roles to View Only option

Tags: sugarcrm

I am  configuring SugarCRM for the users. 
I defined the Roles, there is option like View/Delete/Edit etc, but nowhere I found the "Insert" option. Actually I dont want to give permission some users to create new record for ex. "Documents". But there is option I found to "Insert" permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the role "Edit" role in SugarCRM CE controls both INSERT and UPDATE for records. There is no option for only restricting INSERT, while allowing UPDATE.

Comment: Hi, Ajay. I don't know any easy fix for this. You might try to make a override the menu for the module, check for a specific named role, and only show the create button, if the role matches. (And also check the role when documents are created).  See "[SugarCRM Docs for shortcut overrides](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.1/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.1.0-Chapter%204%20Customizing%20Sugar.html#9000087)" for more info.